# Is there any way of sending DTMF tones during a call with linphone?

Tags: iphone, ios, sip, dtmf

I'm trying to send a sequence of DTMF tones during a SIP call from linphone, compiled for the iPhone, in order to do some call management at a local exchange I've set up. I see from the code that the individual digits send DTMF (without audio on the line), but I can't seem to send a string of digits manually.

When I try, I just get a single digit sent. I could put in a delay and timer, but that just doesn't seem the way to go about it - and a long string of tones would take a long time to send with the necessary acknowledgements.

I've read that you can send DTMF as part of a SIP INFO message, but can't find the facility in linphone to construct a SIP INFO message.

Has anyone been able to do this or have any suggestions as to what I could try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me, changing the audio codec to speex @ 32000 Hz solved the problem. I'm not sure exactly why it solved it, but beforehand DTMF signals were not being recoknized by the server, whereas now they are.

For reference, I'm using the recent Linphone 3.8.1 build.

Comment: That fixed it for me too. Thanks!

Comment: @user1079052 - the settings in the older 3.x builds allowed you to choose the audio codec, I found that choosing a codec with a higher bitrate did the trick for me..

Comment: Where can I find the settings? I am running 3.9.1

Comment: There is no clue in the UI, but you can drag to re-order the audio codecs. Speex @ 32000 is already present. Just drag it to the top and enable it